# GitLab CI/CD build/pipeline only triggered once instead of twice

Tags: yaml, gitlab, pipeline, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I'm using GitLab CI/CD (EDIT: v10.2.2).

I've got 2 branches in my project: `devel` and `testing`

Both are protected.

`devel` is the default branch.

The workflow is: I push on `devel`, then I merge `devel` into `testing` through a merge request.

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` v1:

```
docker_build:                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      stage: build                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      only:                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            - devel                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      script:                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            - docker build -t gitlab.mydomain.com:4567/myproject/app:debug1 .                                                                                                                                                         
            - docker login -u="$DOCKER_LOGIN" -p="$DOCKER_PWD" gitlab.mydomain.com:4567                                                                                                                                            
            - docker push gitlab.mydomain.com:4567/myproject/app:debug1
```

**When I push a modification on `devel`, the script is run and the build is made. Perfect.**

Now same thing with branch `testing`, here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` v2:

```
docker_build:                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      stage: build                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      only:                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            - testing                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      script:                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            - docker build -t gitlab.mydomain.com:4567/myproject/app:debug2 .                                                                                                                                                         
            - docker login -u="$DOCKER_LOGIN" -p="$DOCKER_PWD" gitlab.mydomain.com:4567                                                                                                                                            
            - docker push gitlab.mydomain.com:4567/myproject/app:debug2
```

When I push a modification directly on `testing`, the same thing happens using the `testing` branch. **But here the pipeline on `testing` (and on `testing` only, so only once) is also triggered when I push on `devel`, then merge on `testing`, which is perfect**.

Now `.gitlab-ci.yml` v3, which is nothing else than a concatenation of the two previous versions:

```
docker_build:                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      stage: build                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      only:                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            - devel                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      script:                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            - docker build -t gitlab.mydomain.com:4567/myproject/app:debug1 .                                                                                                                                                         
            - docker login -u="$DOCKER_LOGIN" -p="$DOCKER_PWD" gitlab.mydomain.com:4567                                                                                                                                            
            - docker push gitlab.mydomain.com:4567/myproject/app:debug1


docker_build:                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      stage: build                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      only:                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            - testing                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      script:                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            - docker build -t gitlab.mydomain.com:4567/myproject/app:debug2 .                                                                                                                                                         
            - docker login -u="$DOCKER_LOGIN" -p="$DOCKER_PWD" gitlab.mydomain.com:4567                                                                                                                                            
            - docker push gitlab.mydomain.com:4567/myproject/app:debug2
```

**My expectation was**: when I push on `devel`, then create/accept a merge request from `devel` to `testing`, the `devel` pipeline should run right after my push, then the `testing` pipeline should run right after my merge request acceptance.

**Instead here is what's happening**: only the `devel` pipeline is triggered after the push. The `testing` pipeline will never be triggered after my merge request.

I assume I'm missing something about how GitLab works but I can't figure out what despite my researches.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you checked that the gitlab-ci file is not changed by the MR? Best practice is to have one definition of the pipeline and differentiate in their based on the branch, like you do with the 'only' keyword. Further if you work with MR the 'testing' pipeline will be triggered two times. Once when the MR is created and a second time when you actually merge the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#jobs states:

```
Each job must have a unique name, ...
```

You have two jobs with the same name `docker_build`. Just give them a different name.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much! I read this page several times though. I guess I read _too much_ documentation to remember every detail sometimes.